# Arduino and MP3 Shield not working simultaneously with information received from Pieszo sensor

Tags: audio, arduino, sensors, business-process-management

The program I am writing essentially enables a person to run/step with a Pieszo sensor attached to the bottom of their shoe and a corresponding track with the same bpm will play through a small speaker that is attached to the MP3shield on the Arduino. This is a prototype for a bigger concept.

Below is what I have so far:

```
// libraries
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SdFat.h>
#include <SdFatUtil.h>
#include <SFEMP3Shield.h>
#include <SimpleTimer.h>

int knockSensor = 0;
int MINIMUM = 520;
int MAXIMUM = 530;
int counter = 0;
int comparativeBPM;

SdFat sd;

SFEMP3Shield MP3player;

SimpleTimer timer;

String trackLibrary[30] = {track001.mp3, track002.mp3, track003.mp3, track004.mp3, track005.mp3, track006.mp3, track007.mp3, track008.mp3, track009.mp3, track010.mp3, track011.mp3, track012.mp3, track013.mp3, track014.mp3, track015.mp3, track016.mp3, track017.mp3, track018.mp3, track019.mp3, track020.mp3, track021.mp3, track022.mp3, track023.mp3, track024.mp3, track25.mp3, track026.mp3, track027.mp3, track028.mp3, track029.mp3, track030.mp3};
//bpms increases by 1 starting with 151 in the track library above so 151-180

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  timer.setInterval(1000, ticker);

  if(!sd.begin(9, SPI_HALF_SPEED)) sd.initErrorHalt();
  if (!sd.chdir("/")) sd.errorHalt("sd.chdir");

  MP3player.begin();
  MP3player.setVolume(10,10);
}

void loop() {
  timer.run();
  if (analogRead(knockSensor) >= MINIMUM && analogRead(knockSensor) <= MAXIMUM) { //if knock is between maximum and minimum threshold
    Serial.println("Step detected"); //print when step detected
    counter = knockSensor++; //increment counter every time step detected
    Serial.println(counter); //print counter value to test
  }
  if (timer == 60000) {
    comparativeBPM = (counter/60)*3; // divide counter by 60s to get BPM and multply by 3 to get average bpm
      if (comparativeBPM >= 151) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track001.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 152) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track002.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 153) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track003.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 154) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track004.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 155) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track005.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 156) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track006.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 157) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track007.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 158) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track008.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 159) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track009.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 160) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track010.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 161) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track011.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 162) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track012.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 163) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track013.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 164) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track014.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 165) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track015.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 166) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track016.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 167) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track017.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 168) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track018.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 169) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track019.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 170) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track020.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 171) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track021.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 172) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track022.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 173) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track023.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 174) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track024.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 175) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track025.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 176) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track026.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 177) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track027.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 178) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track028.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 179) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track029.mp3);
      }
      if (comparativeBPM == 180) {
        MP3player.playTrack(track030.mp3);
      }
    }
    timer.restartTimer(timer);
  } 
}

void ticker() {
  Serial.print("Time (s): ");
  Serial.println(millis()/1000);
}
```

If anyone has any idea how this works, any assistance would be much appreciated. The MP3 shield I am using is a SparkfunMP3 shield and comes with it's own reference libraries here https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/mp3-player-shield-hookup

It makes sense that this should work but I don't know enough about the documentation to figure out why this isn't working! Please help

Comment: Please think about factorize your code, for example use a function to find the mp3 base on comparativeBPM. Try a simpler code to identify where is the problem.